# Make Jquery wait for function to finish

Tags: jquery

Ok so I have this line of code to try to help my issue but its not doing the trick...

```
$.when(update_database()).then(window.location.replace
("http://localhost/kumihangul/dashboard.php"));
```

The update_database() function makes an ajax call to update an item... when it finished updating the last item I want it to redirect to the dahsboard...

The updating goes well until its the last item, it doesn't finish making the update before the window is reloaded so whatever the last item is doesn't get all the information.

That code is all one line I just split it up to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$.when(update_database()).then(updateURL);

function updateURL(){
 window.location.replace("http://localhost/kumihangul/dashboard.php")
}
```